# Pictures when transition take place CSS

Tags: html, css

[Please check the picture first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE6f8.jpg) I have 8 pictures in 4 columns and 2 rows, basically what I'm trying to have is the following: when hovering 2 picture in the first row only the 2 picture should move in 2 row on transition not the whole row. Thanks!

```
.primary,
.secondary,
.third,
.fourth, 
.fifth,
.sixth,
.seventh,
.eight{
       float: left;
       width: 300px;
       height: 420px;
       margin-top: -90px;
       margin-left: 60px;
       overflow: hidden;
       font-size: 0.9em;
       text-align: center;
       display: block;
       border-radius: 10px;
       box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
      -webkit-transition: height 2s; 
              transition: height 2s;
}

.eight:hover,
.seventh:hover,
.sixth:hover,
.fifth:hover,
.fourth:hover,
.third:hover,
.secondary:hover,
.primary:hover {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 550px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: How does your HTML look? can you provide that.

Comment: If you have rows and you make the element in the row bigger...of course it pushes the next row down, what else were you expecting?

Comment: Please provide some HTML to this fiddle, and add it to your question: https://jsfiddle.net/wp9uj9o8/

Comment: we need to see your html. one suggestion might be to keep 2 pics in a column, if you can manage that. That way, you have four columns. 1st and 2nd pics in first column div beneath one another, then 2nd column and so on.

Comment: With fixed height values before and after, as you have here, a negative margin could help counter that effect. Otherwise, for a dynamic amount of content to reveal on hover, so that the actual height is unknown beforehand, you’d rather need to make use of some absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the transition is related to the height, it would be easier to consider using columns that are floated left. Just put a container around every 3 images with the class named `.col` (or whatever class name you want to give it).

Remove the `float` and `display` styles to your images as well:

```
.primary,
.secondary,
.third,
.fourth, 
.fifth,
.sixth,
.seventh,
.eight{
   width: 300px;
   height: 420px; 
   margin-top: -90px;
   margin-left: 60px;
   overflow: hidden;
   font-size: 0.9em;
   text-align: center;
   border-radius: 10px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-transition: height 2s; 
          transition: height 2s;
}

.eight:hover,
.seventh:hover,
.sixth:hover,
.fifth:hover,
.fourth:hover,
.third:hover,
.secondary:hover,
.primary:hover {
    height: 550px;
}

.col{
  height:auto;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:33%;
  float:left;
}
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wp9uj9o8/5/

Comment: thank you ! you're logic worked well

Comment: Glad to have been able to help. Can you accept the answer?

Comment: Yes that was the solution i was looking for. Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the images to zoom on hover rather than transitioning the whole row?

I've had a quick go at replicating and adding a transition on the hover effect. It basically changes the background-size on hover from 110% to 100%.

```
  .primary{
     transition: all 0.2s;
     background-image:url(https://placehold.it/300x550);
     background-size: 110%;
     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-color: gray;
     position: relative;
 }
```

and then on hover

```
.primary:hover {
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/mikbeach/pen/pyKKXv

This codepen shows what I was trying to do in more detail - http://codepen.io/Grawl/pen/DovAI/